# Is map.size() always the same as map.entrySet().size()

Tags: java

Say I have a HashMap:

```
var h = new HashMap();
```

my question is, is:

```
h.size() == h.entrySet().size()
```

always? (Assuming no concurrency issues).

Comment: is `"string".length()` always the same as `"string".toString().length()`?

Comment: No matter how silly this might sound, some people would find this Q. helpful in their pursue for better understanding of map/set corellation in Java, so therefore, constituent answer should be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1002) suggests  it is...

```
final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public final int size() {
        return size;
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

...and my decompiler suggests it as well.

```
public final int size() {
    return HashMap.this.size;
}
```

Note that you will (somewhat ironically) get burned by [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html); this assumption may not hold due to the fact that any modifications to this class would put the state of the size in flux.  Even though this is a thread-safe collection, it's not safe to rely on `size()` to do any kind of logical control like you would with a `HashMap`, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no concurrency issues modifying the `HashMap`, then your expression

```
h.size() == h.entrySet().size()
```

will be `true`.  From the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) for `HashMap`, the method `size()`:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

where `size` is an instance variable declared by `HashMap`.

When you call `entrySet()`, it returns an instance of a nested class called `EntrySet`, and its `size()` method is:

```
public final int size()                 { return size; }
```

Note that `EntrySet` doesn't declare its own `size` variable; it's returning `size` from `HashMap`.

Also note that `keySet()` and `values()` similarly return their own nested classes that are defined practically identically.

So, no matter where you call `size()`, it should return identically, assuming no interference from other threads or other structural modifications between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's always true because a hashmap is just a list of entries. The difference is in the represented form, but the size is the same. (This answer is based on not modifying the HashMap class)